# Convert OrderBy Predicate to Where Predicate based on the current object

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am new to LINQ and creating a generic function that will get the next object based on the current object and the OrderBy predicate. I need to take the property being ordered by and create a where property > currentObject.property.

Is this possible or is there a better way to do this?

```
GetNextArticle(IArticle current, Func<IArticle, bool> where, Func<IArticle, IComparable> orderBy)
    {
        return Articles.Where(where && x => x.[orderByIComparable] > current.[orderByIComparable]).OrderBy(orderBy)
    }
```

I hope this make sense

**Solution**

```
    public IArticle GetNextArticle(IArticle current, Func<IArticle, bool> where, Func<IArticle, IComparable> orderBy)
    {
        var articles = NewsItems
            .Where(where)
            .OrderBy(orderBy)
            .SkipWhile(a => a.PageId != current.PageId);

        return articles.Count() > 1 ? articles.Skip(1).Take(1).First() : null;
    }
```

Comment: What is your expected linq expression can you share it as lambda?

Comment: I would order the list and then find where current item is in the list.  Then return the index before the current item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand what I mean, but I *think* you want the next article in the passed order, so one way would be this:

1. Order the articles
2. Find the current one
3. Return the next one

This assumes an `Id` property exists:

```
return Articles
   .Where(where)
   .OrderBy(orderBy)
   .SkipWhile(a => a.Id != current.Id)
   .Skip(1)
   .Take(1);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I required except the TakeWhile needs to be SkipWhile